# How to use 'select_related' with get_object_or_404?

Tags: django, django-models, django-select-related

Is there any way of using [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) and [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) together or any other way to achieve the result of using these two together(except from putting it in try/except)??

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Yes.

```
obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel.objects.select_related(), whatever=whatever)
```

Comment: Can use multiple where close here 
obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel.objects.select_related(), whatever=whatever, another=another)