# How to use "select_for_update()" to get an object in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset, select-for-update

As the Django Documentation says, [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) returns a `Queryset`. But `get` does not. Now I have a query which I am sure is going to return only one tuple. But I also need to acquire locks for this transaction. So I am doing something like:

```
ob = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().filter(some conditions)
```

Now, I need to modify some values of `ob`. But `ob` is a `Queryset`. This seems pretty simple, but beats me. I'm pretty new to Django. Some advice please.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just call `get`, slice it, etc. and save as usual. The lock is in place through the transaction.

```
ob = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=1)
```

Any changes are committed at the end of the transaction (which by default through 1.5 is per-request)

Comment: So instead of doing a filter I can directly do `select_for_update()` on `get`?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta No, the order isn't correct. You use `get` on `select_for_update()` as `get` returns an object, not a QuerySet.

Comment: I didn't the get the 1.5 thingie in your last statement. pls clarify

Comment: 1.5 refers to the version of Django. The default behavior is for the lock to be in place until the end of the request.

Answer (score 49):

You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6624655/538284) also use `select_for_update` with `get_object_or_404` function:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

with transaction.atomic():
    obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel.objects.select_for_update(), pk=pk)
    # do some stuff with locked obj
```

Answer (score 1):

Just after **`select_for_update().filter()`**, you can put [**.first()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) which returns **the 1st object of a queryset** to update it with [**save()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) as shown below. *You can see [**my question and answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842206/are-there-any-other-cases-which-select-for-update-doesnt-work-but-works-wit) explaining more about `select_for_update()` in Django:

```py
                                                                # Here
ob = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().filter(some conditions).first()
ob.field_1 = 'some value'
ob.save()
```