# get_object_or_404 with relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset

I suppose this must be possible judging by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624530/django-using-select-related-and-get-object-or-404-together) but I can't seem to work out the syntax.  I need to get the blog object with the picture field via the author foreign key.

Is this possible with get_object_or_404, and if so how?

```
#models.py
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)

#author
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    picture = models.ImageField()

blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Sounds like you mean `get_object_or_404(Blog, author__picture='somefilename.jpg')`, but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Your blog object will have access to the author and profile. blog.author.picture should yield your result though it will cause a query.

Comment: ok right, i understand.  so in 1 one query i just want to get the blog by id, and also the author picture.  I guess that's not possible with get_object_or_404?

Comment: It does seem possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624530/django-using-select-related-and-get-object-or-404-together

Comment: Yep, it does seem so, but i'm struggling to figure out how without a concrete example..

Comment: You don't have to fetch them both. Get Blog object first and then use blog.author.picture whenever you need to use The picture.

Comment: That's 2 database hits though isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The query you want is like so (from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)):

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    hometown = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

And then your query is:

```
b = Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').get(id=4)
p = b.author         # Doesn't hit the database.
c = p.hometown       # Doesn't hit the database.

b = Book.objects.get(id=4) # No select_related() in this example.
p = b.author         # Hits the database.
c = p.hometown       # Hits the database.
```

except in your case your query would be: `Picture.objects.select_related('author__blog').get(picture_name='somefilename.jpg')`

You're saying I want the picture (and while your at it, the Author and their Blog) that relates to the picture name 'somefilename.jpg'. At least if I've understood your question and DB structure it is.

Comment: Well this was certainly a long time ago and whilst i appreciate it wasn't explained very well, it seems that @victor-chris-cabral had the correct reponse which is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624530/django-using-select-related-and-get-object-or-404-together

Comment: @rix absolutely, but an answer is always better than a comment (comments disappear more easily). Also this should constitute a concrete example, for anyone else coming here.

Answer (score 0):

As Pureferret suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048166/11782743)
 you can do it in following way,

```
blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
author = blog.author
```

and if you want to show that image in template just use

```
{{ auther.picture.url }}
```